# Yii is not auto including jquery

Tags: php, jquery, yii

I have a strange problem with Yii & Jquery:

When I open a page which uses ajax/jquery on localhost Yii does automatically add asset include calls to the  of the page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/PATH/assets/f72b359d/style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/PATH/assets/2e442e1a/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/PATH/assets/2e442e1a/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
```

However when I run same code on the server Yii does not do it hense no Jquery available.

I'd appreciate if someone could direct to a way to solve it.

Comment: I never used Yii but here is my guess, tried using absolute path instead of relative?

Comment: What do you mean "does not do it"? Are the tags not inside `<head>` at all?

Comment: Or try using the Google CDN (Content Delivery Network) to serve jQuery: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js

Comment: There is no guarantee that YII will put assets in the same place on the server as it does on localhost. Are you sure that the paths are right? the 2e442e1a part in paths like src="/PATH/assets/2e442e1a/jquery.js" will change

Comment: Do not include Yii's assets with such paths src="/PATH/assets/2e442e1a/jquery.js". You should include/register JS code with via CClientScript methods which you get by Yii::app()->getClientScript().

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It seems like you're not registering jQuery in the correct way. You must add the following line in `/protected/views/layout/main.php` before **`</head>`** tag:

```
<?php Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('jquery'); ?>
```

It will load jQuery automatically. Remember, if the **YII_DEBUG** flag is on it will load non-minified version, when deactivated (on production) it will load minified version. Hope this will fix your problem.

Comment: Actually the location of that line doesn't matter. You can place it in a controller, in a view, etc. But I don't think that is the problem here

Comment: That was the solution. I did not explicitly register jQuery as for some reason it was working fine so I didn't even know I should do it. It have just occurred to me that it was working because Yii Debug Toolbar was including jQuery for me and that toolbar was switched off on the server.

Answer (score 1):

If all is working on your local machine it might be a permission problems

Have you checked that /assets is writable on your server ?

Yii publishes the assets it needs at runtime in this directory

Comment: That was the first thing I have checked and all directories are writable.