# Yii is not auto including jquery assets online

Tags: php, jquery, yii, assets

My problem is :

Yii is not auto including jquery assets on the production server but it does perfectly in local...

on the server this line miss...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/20c35dd5/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/20c35dd5/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
```

i don't know where but in local Yii publish the folder situatued there:

```
yii\framework\web\js\source
```

it has never worked online and i might forgot some rights but the other assets are published whitout any problem....

the only différence is in local yii is in c:/yii/... and online i put i on the protected folder.. ( i not sure it's the best way !)

i know i can include it manually but it's not my goal..

I'd appreciate if someone could help me to find a way to solve it.

Comment: I don't think it should be in protected folder, I mean jquery. place your jquery where your other assets are.

Comment: do you have an assets directory?  I know I've seen issues where the directory doesn't get created automatically, so I need to create one first . . .

Comment: Found almost the same question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122502/yii-is-not-auto-including-jquery

Comment: Use `<?php Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('jquery'); ?>` for include. Assets path can change.

Comment: I guess I had assumed those lines in your HTML were the result of having used `registerCoreScript()`, but if you manually put those lines into your view, then things won't work.  The [assets directory](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/148/understanding-assets/) is dynamically created and managed by Yii, mainly to avoid naming collisions

Comment: yes i have some other asset already publish.. You right ernie and i need to known why yii don't work for this... i think i need too include yii somehere else than the index.php...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use yii debug toolbar and it publish Jquery in local... but not online...

so i have to use

```
 <?php Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('jquery'); ?>
```